# Find first match in every folder branch respectively

Tags: command-line, find

Given the following folder layout:

```
Current_folder
└── FolderA
|   └── CMakeList.txt
|   └── FolderAA
|       └── CMakeList.txt
|
└── FolderB
|   └── FolderBA
|   |   └── CMakeList.txt
|   |   └── FolderBAA
|   |       └── CMakeList.txt
|   |
|   └── FolderBB
|       └── CMakeList.txt
|
└── FolderC
    └── CMakeList.txt
    └── FolderCA
        └── CMakeList.txt
```

How can I use `find` (or any other tool) to produce an output similar to:

```
Current_folder/FolderA/CMakeList.txt
Current_folder/FolderB/FolderBA/CMakeList.txt
Current_folder/FolderB/FolderBB/CMakeList.txt
Current_folder/FolderC/CMakeList.txt
```

Meaning that the search is stopped after a match with the literal "CMakeLists.txt" for each recursive folder branch respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was the following bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
file_of_interest="CMakeList.txt"
latest_directory_wih_match=""

for current_directory in $(find -type d);
do
  if [[ (${latest_directory_wih_match} == "") || (! ${current_directory} == ${latest_directory_wih_match}*) ]];
  then
    if [ -f ${current_directory}/${file_of_interest} ]
    then
      latest_directory_wih_match=${current_directory}
      echo ${latest_directory_wih_match}/${file_of_interest}
    fi
  fi;
done
```

@dessert's answer worked for the minimal example above as well. Using it on my actual folder structure (~4000 folders) it was still giving wrong results. I'm not sure why, to be honest.

When I tried @muru's solution it wouldn't stop executing. I guess the function calling itself isn't aborting properly? Not sure about the reason here either.

PS: In an actual CMake Project the file is actually called "CMakeLists.txt" (note the extra s in the end). I spotted this error only after answers were already provided.

Comment: I took the freedom to add the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Answer (score 1):

A shell function (untested):

```bsh
search () (
  if [ -f "$1"/CMakeList.txt ]
  then
    # if you get a file, print and stop recursing
    echo "${1%/}/CMakeList.txt"
    return
  fi
  for d in "$1"/*/
  do
    # nothing found in this directory, recurse to subdirectories
    search "${d%/}"
  done
)
search .
```

Comment: Probably better to strip a trailing slash from `$1` or `$d`: `"${1%/}/CMakeList.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this:

```bsh
for path in ./*;do find "$path" -type f -name "CMakeList.txt" -print -quit ;done
./FolderA/CMakeList.txt
./FolderB/FolderBB/CMakeList.txt
./FolderC/CMakeList.txt
```

This will print the file's path and `-quit` as soon as first file with matched name found from each *path* that feeding to `find "$path"`.

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm for the example I provided originally. I'm afraid I did not phrase my question precisely though. For I would like to search all subbranches recursively as well, not only the top level branches. In your currently provided solution the entry `Current_folder/FolderB/FolderBB/CMakeLists.txt` is missed. I have updated the question accordingly.
Same is true for @dessert's answer, btw.

Comment: @Tano Please try whether `for path in *; do find "$path" -type f -regex "[^/]*/CMakeList.txt" -print -quit -o -regex "[^/]*/[^/]*/CMakeList.txt" -print; done` matches the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

[αғsнιη's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1012795/507051) contains the correct solution with `find`, but if you have a *lot* of directories calling one `find` after another can be quite slow. If you want to make use of all your CPU cores and run the `find` processes in parallel I recommend [GNU `parallel`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/parallel) for the task:

```bsh
parallel find {} -type f -regex "[^/]*/CMakeList.txt" -print -quit -o -regex "[^/]*/[^/]*/CMakeList.txt" -print ::: */
```

Comment: Is it faster? It depends: https://oletange.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/parallel-disk-io-is-it-faster/